# JavaScript xPath command does not run co-mingled with Selenium Java program on every run

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, xpath, automation

The below javascript (co-mingled with Java in Selenium) does not run xpath command successfully **on every run**. However my Java command runs successfully, it's the xpath that I'm having issues with. (In other words, sometimes xpath command runs successfully and at other times it does not). I changes jdk from 13 to jdk8, and that didn't work. I don't know what's needed.

I'm new with learning automation testing and I'm teaching myself.

Here's the command line:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='button' and @data-test-id='checkbox']")).click();
```

**Error response:**

```
JavaScript error: , line 0: NotAllowedError: The play method is not
allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context,
possibly because the user denied permission.
Exception in thread "main"
org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: The element
reference of <button class="c27KHO0_n b_0 M_0 i_0 I_T y_Z2uhb3X
A_6EqO r_P C_q cvhIH6_T ir3_1JO2M7 P_0" type="button"> is stale;
either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not
in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed
```

Comment: `oes not run xpath command successfully on every run` what error message you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

**StaleElementReferenceException**: occurs when elements is not attached to DOM please use explicit wait and check :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(
        ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@type='button' and @data-test-id='checkbox']"))).click();
```

Comment: Explicit wait and stateElement Ref are not related. `Explicit wait` will be used to make sure the script wait until the explicit condition met (meaning until the element is clickable in your above code). where as `staleElement Reference Exception` occurs when you are referring to the older element reference of the element in your script.

Comment: StaleElementReferenceException is due to unavailability of an element accessed by findelement/findelements method.
I have added WebDriverWait to make sure element is available before  performing any action on an element (If you have a doubt on availability of that element)

Comment: if the element is not present on the DOM you will get `No Such Element` exception. Yes, your idea and solution is good and the term `stale element exception` is the one which is misleading here.

Comment: Stale element reference exception occurs when element we are tryiing to interact with is destroyed and then recreated again.Due to this ref of element in the DOM becomes stale and we are not getting reference of element

Comment: @supputuri thank you for the wait condition.  When click() is added to the end of the command, I received: Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to WebElement.  So, I remove click() so it reads follows: WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement button=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@type='button' and @data-test-id='checkbox']")));
    
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='button' and @data-test-id='checkbox']")).click();

Comment: It's working fine now. But, please let me know if there's another way where I can incorporate Click() without have the extra command line.  Again, thank you so much.  This has helped me immensely!

Comment: @Rock thank you for the revised code.  It's works!  I greatly appreciate your time and effort!

Comment: Would you be kind enough to accept my answer and hit upvote button too